# really quick question about product sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I am currently reading Folland. Most of the definition of the product $\sigma$-algebra I understand i.e. $\{\pi^{-1}_{\alpha}(E_{\alpha}):E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha},\alpha \in A\}$ is the generating set on $\Pi X_{\alpha}$. The thing I am confused about from the definition is "$E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$". Are we only taking one set from each sigma algebra of $X_{\alpha}$? Or, does the generating set have more than one $\pi^{-1}_{\alpha}(E_{\alpha})$ from the same $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: See the answer of Anne. A third way (my favourite) to denote it is: $$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(\mathcal M_{\alpha})$$ where $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(\mathcal M_{\alpha})$ is accepted as a notation of $\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E)\mid E\in\mathcal M_{\alpha}\}$.

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion is justified: this formula is not clean. It should be
$$\{\pi^{-1}_{\alpha}(E):E \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha},
\alpha \in A
\},$$
or equivalently
$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}
\{\pi^{-1}_{\alpha}(E):E \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}\}.$$